# Python, paramiko, errono 10061 while trying to shh from windows to linux

Tags: python, paramiko

My Code is:

```
ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect('somehost.com',username='someuser',password='secretpw')
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.connect('somehost.com',username='someuser',password='secretpw')
```

I get the following message:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\paramiko\client.py", line 251, in connect
File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\paramiko\util.py", line 270, in   retry_on_signal
File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\paramiko\client.py", line 251, in <lambda>
File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target
 machine actively refused it
```

The "paramiko" version is 1.15.2.

Another note is that another person install "paramiko" on a Linux box and was able to do a SSH connection to other machines.

I am also able to connect with Putty on ip address and the port I am using with paramiko

Comment: 'Actively refused' means that there is either a firewall blocking the connection or somehow the program isn't running. Are you sure you have the right host/port/credentials? Can you try running ssh from the same machine (I assume not because it looks like you are remoting into a server hosted by someone else).

Comment: I am very sure of the credentials, I have checked them several times.  I am not sure which machine you want me to try to ssh from.  I did not supply the machine name, port, user name or password because they belong to the company I work for.  I can try to ssh into other machine from my windows machine by hand instead of using the app that calls putty.  I did just copy the information to access the machine from another user who has it working.